# What is wrong with this simple jQuery code?

Tags: jquery

What is wrong with this jquery code, the error received on IE is

> Message: Expected ';'
>   Line: 10
>   Char: 10

All I want is to move the mouse over and have an alter pop-up

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#t').bind('onmouseover',function(){
        target: '#t',
        success: function(){
            alert('test');
            }

    });

});
</script>

<div id="t">testing mouse over</div>
```

Thanks
Dave

Comment: How about using a JS debugger or at least an editor that offers JS syntax highlighting? Then you know what's wrong.

Comment: So often I feel like the answer to, "How do I fix this?" is, "Be a programmer" :-)

Comment: @Pointy - I know it's Saturday, but be nice.  :o)

Comment: How about you have a look at the examples here: http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Comment: Also, a 'success' function is used in the jQuery $.ajax command, but not in event binding.

Answer (score 2):

It's syntactically incorrect.  Your call to "bind" should take a function as its second argument, but you've got the syntax of functions and that of object literals jumbled up.  I don't know what you want to do so I can't really say how to correct it.

Here's how you'd do an alert on mouseover:

```
$('#t').bind('mouseover', function(ev) {
  alert('test');
});
```

Also note that you leave off the "on" in the event name.

Comment: Is it not taking function as its second argument?
correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Jean: No, it **takes** a function as second parameter but the **syntax** of your function is **wrong**.

Comment: It is, but what you typed in is NOT a function. It's a syntax error.

Comment: Pointy and Felix are right. The 'function' you passed as a parameter is broken. You put it in the right place, but as a function, it simply will not operate. When you refer to `target:`, I assume you want a reference back to the element with the event. This is done so through `$(this)`. Taking Pointy's example, try `alert($(this).attr('id'))`. It will display the id of the element that received the event.

Comment: If you don't like alerts (can't blame you) use `$('body').append('test <br />')` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#t').bind('onmouseover',function(){
            alert('test');
     });
});
```

The `target` and `success` code you put into your code is simply invalid. The second argument for the `bind` function must take a function as an argument, and what you wrote was attempting to pass it an object literal, and not even succeeding at that.